# Check if xdebug is running

Tags: php, xdebug

I have some AJAX queries executing repeatedly.
So, if xdebug is running, I don't want to execute any of them.

Question is: how to determine in PHP code, whether xdebug is currently running?

Comment: Wouldn't xdebug be loaded on all the requests anyway?

Answer (score 5):

From Xdebug v2.6 You can use the `xdebug_is_debugger_active()` function: "Returns whether a debugging session is active" (from https://xdebug.org/docs/all_functions )

If you are not sure that Xdebug is even installed or enabled, check that first before calling this function or you can always use `function_exists( 'xdebug_is_debugger_active' ) && xdebug_is_debugger_active()` as a condition.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to ask [extension_loaded](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php) about xdebug.

Comment: No, this is not a solution. Extension is permanently written in php.ini, and is loaded every time, of course.

`xdebug_is_enabled()` does the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
php -v
```

inside your command line.

If xDebug is running, you should get an extended string, something like:

with Xdebug v2.5.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derrick Rethans